# How to add an index to the DB column 'class' used for inheritance in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

When using **table-per-hierarchy** inheritance, GORM creates a 'class' column that stores the classname of instances.

I want to add DB index to this column, since many of my SQL queries include `where class='com.myapp.Mychildclass'` . However, I didn't succeed with this code:

```
static mapping = { 
    columns { 
        'class' column: 'class', index: 'class_idx' 
    } 
}
```

I tried different versions of this code without having the index created.

How can I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the answer of this question here:
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GORM-Howto-index-the-inheritance-class-column-td1563116.html

UPDATE : link updated

Comment: I was just about to ask this exact question.. Your link to nabble is dead, how can the index be added (except manually)?